# Do I need to resize downloaded image in code instead of IB to get better performance?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

In Android, good practice is before loading the image, resizing it in code because resizing by system is expensive. I don't know if it's also true in iOS. For example, I'm using uitableview to show some images downloaded from internet, each cell has an image. I don't know the size of each image. However, when it's showed in the table, I want size of each image 75x75. To achieve good performance, should I resize images in code before loading them? Or I can just set the size in interface builder. Do they have the same performance? Thanks!

Comment: No you don't need to do that , just set the imageView a proper size.

Comment: The image *should* have the dimension which is suitable when it is rendered. There is no reason for images to have larger dimensions than the canvas where they are rendered. This will only waste system resources.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper, thanks, this is the answer I want.

Answer (score 0):

I think resizing the images through code will give better performance as the inferface builder will just resize the image and will not optimise it.

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image convertToSize:(CGSize)size 
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
    UIImage *destImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return destImage;
}
```

use above code to resize